# Django Foreign Key Relationship And Creation

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys

I have the following:
**models.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    passwd = models.CharField()
    sessionID = models.CharField()

class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    school = models.CharField()
    name = models.CharField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
```

I don't understand how to create Users and StudentProfiles in django and have them linked. Could somebody please provide some sample code for creating a User, then creating a StudentProfile that refers to the User. Could they also post sample access code, ie let's say I have an email, please show how I would lookup the User, and then access the accompanying Profile information. Could I write a method as part of the User model to do this?

inb4 Why aren't you using the Django User model? 
This is as much of a thought exercise as anything, I also want to roll my own because the Django stuff was much more than I needed. I prefer it sweet and simple.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As addition to zhyfer's answer – You can approach things even a bit more basic:

```
user = User()
user.email = 'anon@anon.com'
user.save()

profile = StudentProfile()
profile.school = 'MIT'
profile.user = user
profile.save()
```

To get the related items you can also use the [related manager](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager):

`user.profile_set.all()[0]` should return the related `StudentProfile` for the created  user.

And therefore `user.profile_set.all()[0].school` should return `MIT` while
`profile.user.email` returns `anon@anon.com`

This all is a bit more elaborated in this blog post: [Doing things with Django models](http://uswaretech.com/blog/2010/01/django-models-tutorial/)

And finally you could write the `get_profile` method of the `user`-model like this:

```
def get_profile(self):
    return self.profile_set.all()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the above models,you can access a profile given an email via:

```
profile = StudentProfile.objects.get(user__email = 'test@test.com')
school = profile.school
```

I think that if you want a method in the user model to do this you can basically do the same thing:

```
def get_profile(email):
    return StudentProfile.objects.get(user__email = 'test@test.com')
```

To Link:

```
u = User.objects.create(email="test@test.com", passwd="test", sessionId=1) 
StudentProfile.objects.create(school="test", name="student", user=u)
```

Comment: u = User.objects.create(email="test@test.com", passwd="test", sessionId=1)
StudentProfile.objects.create(school="test", name="student", user=u)